# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ the initial rook?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

By a *rook*, let us mean a unital, not-necessarily associative [near-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring) satisfying $x0=0$.

> **Question.** Is $\mathbb{Z}$ the initial object in the category of rooks?

(I hope so, since this is my only motivation for defining the concept of a rook.)

Here's an explicit list of axioms:

1. $x+0=x$
2. $0+x=x$
3. $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
4. $-x+x = 0$
5. $x+-x=0$
6. $x1=x$
7. $1x=x$
8. $(x+y)z=xz+yz$
9. $x0=0$

Comment: "I hope so, since this is my only motivation for defining the concept of a rook." If your only motivation for defining a category is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object, then why are you not satisfied with category of rings?

Comment: @RghtHndSd, because this is way cooler; in this scenario, all four of (0) the commutativity of addition, (1) the associativity of multiplication, (2) the commutativity of multiplication, and (3) the left distributive law; they all *follow* from the definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ (if it works). They're not put in there artificially. Also, note that the more objects we have in our category, the stronger the claim that some particular object is initial.

Comment: @goblin: This is no proper motivation for introducing such a concept. It is artificial to omit associativity of multiplication! (At least, in our world.)

Comment: Isn't this the structure you get when you look at the set of endomaps of a group, with $+$ being the pointwise group operation and juxtaposition being composition?

Comment: @ZhenLin, yes, good point. If $G$ is an additively denoted group, then the set of all $0$ preserving functions $G \rightarrow G$ forms a rook. So that is certainly a nice motivation. BUT that rook will always be associative, so we haven't managed to motivate to absence of a multiplicative associativity axiom.

Comment: Oh, actually I was thinking of the other absorption axiom, $0 x = 0$, because then there is no restriction on the endomaps.

Comment: @goblin: There is no doubt in my mind that the pursuit of which axioms one may remove is a noble one. But can you name a natural object that forms a rook and is not (say) associative? I don't see how one can claim something to be natural if there are no natural examples.

Comment: @RghtHndSd, hey bud, sorry I can't. I'll let you know if anything shows up.

Answer (score 4):

If $R$ is a "rook", there is a unique homomorphism of groups $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ mapping $1$ to $1$, and hence $n$ to $n 1:=\underbrace{1+1+\dotsc}_{n}$. We only have to show that it is multiplicative, i.e. that $(n 1) (m 1) = (nm) 1$. Using 8. one reduces to the case that $n=1$, but then it follows from 7.

Since you want the axioms to be minimal: It is well-known that 5. follows from 1-4. For the proof that $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial we don't need 6. And we don't need 9.

PS: It doesn't make much sense to define a category of algebraic structures by random axioms and look for an initial object, when you don't know interesting examples of these structures yet. An example of a non-associative and non-distributive "rook" is the free "rook" on one generator $x$. Remark that here we cannot simplify $x(2x)$ or $x(x^2)$, which is quite nasty. I doubt that "rooks" are interesting ...

Comment: No it does not follow from 6. For example, look at $3 \cdot 2=6$. When we want to prove this in a rook, we cannot use $2=1+1$ and use the distributive law to reduce this to $3 \cdot 1 = 3$, since only the other distributive law is available. So we write $3=1+1+1$ and reduce to $1 \cdot 2 = 2$.